# advantage and disadvantage developing app programmatically without storyboard and xib

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xib

What is advantage and disadvantage not using storyboard and xib.
I am building an application without using storyboard and xib, what happen if project is build programatically.

Comment: You waste more time doing it.

Comment: The only imaginable advantage is that sometimes storyboards don't play nice with source control.  Other than that, it's a pile of disadvantages.  Develop time will be longer, maintainability will be extraordinarily difficult...

Comment: initial building isn't a big problem at all but support can grows to real pain in one place

Comment: if you build it programmatically you have more control. 90 % of developers I know use only code

Comment: Building it programmatically doesn't give you control.   Anything you need to do programmatically you can still do programmatically, even if you use IB for the other 98% of it.

Comment: In the end it comes down to saving time and having a clean working solution. Sure, coding things directly helps in certain circumstances, but its usually when the storyboard or IB is getting in the way. To build the whole UI in code definitely wastes time doing it, as well as in the long run.

Comment: @nhgrif in my opinion xibs and storyboards even more are almost useless. There are so many things you can't do in a storyboard. Too lazy to write them all here. I do not insist on my opinion though and I admit that I can be  just not aware of some important things.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I buid it with programmaticaly.....!!!

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I'm guessing that perhaps it's been a while since you've messed with Xibs/Storyboards perhaps, or you haven't spent that much time with them.  There are only a very, very few auto layout constraints that I can't quite set through IB... but that's the only limitation I can remember running into especially since `IBDesignable`/`IBInspectable` was introduced.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I am building enterprise application,  which do have more then 50+ screens,  I felt pragmatically implementation is best way to do the project.  Very easy to handle the deprecated methods too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storyboards dont only speed up development, but they also help identify UX issues and get an overview of the current UX of an application.

Software should be built with the future in mind and the storyboard allows an entry point into the project for other developers or designers, as well as yourself, if you for some reason left the project for a while.

Having everything in code or even xib files wastes time, even great documentation is slower to process that a visual layout of the apps UI.

Xibs on their own can cause design issues.

For performance, storyboards are optimized.

Overall as the name suggests, its the visual story or flow for your app. You should also split different functionality of your app into different storyboards e.g. if you have a side menu that loads different view stacks, use different storyboards as needed.

Obviously its not 1 or the other with storyboards and code, it depends on the situation, you might even use a xib here and there. Software is dynamic and new ideas come about, not all have fixed solutions, that would be boring.